# Mongoid named scope comparing two time fields in the same document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I need to create a named scope in Mongoid that compares two Time fields within the same document. Such as

`scope :foo, :where => {:updated_at.gt => :checked_at}`

This obviously won't work as it treats `:checked_at` as a symbol, not the actual field. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

**Update 1**

Here is my model where I have this scope declared, with a lot of extra code stripped out.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :checked_at, :type => Time

  scope :unresolved, :where => { :updated_at.gt => self.checked_at }
end
```

This gives me the following error:

`'<class:User>': undefined method 'checked_at' for User:Class (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, mongodb doesn't support queries against dynamic values.
But you could use a javascript function:

```
scope :unresolved, :where => 'this.updated_at >= this.checked_at'
```

To speed this up you could add an attribute like "is_unresolved" which will be set to true on update when this condition is matched ( and index that ).

Comment: Awesome, this works great. Also thanks for the performance suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

```
scope :foo, :where => {:updated_at.gt => self.checked_at}
```

For example, this will work:

```
scope :foo, where(:start_date.lte=>Date.today.midnight)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `undefined method `checked_at' for User:Class (NoMethodError)`. The 2nd statement will work, since you are passing in an object. I need to compare two fields that is part of the same document/model.

Comment: Need you to post your user class -- just the mongoid include and the definition for checked_at and your scope

Comment: I edited the original question with the User class. Thanks for your time thus far Jesse.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'll like this method, it's not the best, but it should work.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :checked_at, :type => Time

  scope :unresolved, lambda{ |user| where(:updated_at.gt => user.checked_at) }
end
```

You call it with User.unresolved(my_user_object)
It seems now after rereading your post that this probably won't do what you want.  If this is true, then you will probably need to use MapReduce or possibly Baju's method (have not tested it)