# Mongoid order_by with multiple fields resulting unexpected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have followed [two.mongoid.org doc](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#order_by), seems something is off with `order_by` on multiple fields.

I am having a `Link` model with `title` and `link_order` fields, and first I want to sort records by `link_order` than `created_at`.

but not getting expected result:

I am expecting this order `['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

```
---------------
title | link_order
---------------
a     | 0
b     | 0
c     | 0
d     | 0
e     | 1
---------------
```

---

```
Link.order_by([[:created_at, :asc]]).collect(&:title)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Link.order_by([[:link_order, :desc], [:created_at, :asc]]).collect(&:title)
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

---

Comment: i think the problem is in sorting with created_at...this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659967/time-gt-query-not-working-with-mongoid-and-ruby-on-rails/22672030#22672030) shows problem when querying with created at... and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3927498/1769515) state that timestamps comparing with mongoid have problems...

Comment: maybe you should look at using [mongoid-metastamp](https://github.com/sporkd/mongoid-metastamp) in comparison instead of  `Mongoid::Timestamps`

Answer (score 4):

In MongoDB as _id is created by timestamp only. You can try below query and I think it should work fine

```
 Link.order_by(:link_order.desc,:_id.asc).collect(&:title)
```